# BOOST Asio async_write_some vs asio::async_write , force a single write operation

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, usb, boost-asio

Some special files have semantics associated with individual writes. (*For example, FunctionFS (USB gadgets in userspace) associates a single write to a sequence of USB packets within a single USB transfer. Two writes will never be merged into a single USB packet. Hence the first write may end with a short packet.*)

I therefore don't want to use `asio::async_write`, because it allows zero or more calls to the underlying `async_write_some` of the passed stream. However if I use `stream.async_write_some` directly, it allows that not all the data will have been written.

What I need is the guarantee that the streams's `async_write_some` (of `posix::basic_stream_descriptor`) passes all buffers in the sequence to the vectored write system call, and write less data only when the system call decides to do so.

How can I achieve that? Am I on the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you use in terms of POSIX API? Likely it ends up the exact same underlying API that ASIO hooks into. So, if that API behaves in the way you describe you can expect ASIO to behave in the same way (not resulting in partial completions).

The only place where I readily know ASIO might have opinions on buffer division/operation is the other way around where SSL buffer-sequences may be combined prior to writes for performance reasons.

It would help if we knew both interfaces you're trying to contrast/impact analyze. E.g. there will be a difference between using `asio::posix::stream_descriptor` or `asio::serial_port` for obvious reasons. There might be platform differences at play, but I assume the platform is Linux because of FunctionFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use stream_descriptor (boost 1.74) but will soon update to 1.80 and use stream_file, as that uses io_uring and allows to use async_write_some with real async behavior rather than epoll+sync syscalls. I supect at the moment my best bet might be to use `async_write_some` with a `assert` at the  completion handler that all bytes have been written (or an error happened).

Comment: One of my worries was that if I pass too many buffers in my buffer sequence, async_write may split the sequence up and call async_write_some with only some of the buffers in the sequence (I dug in the sources and found that to track how many bytes were written, it converts all buffers to const_buffer and adds them to a vector of some statically allocated size to avoid malloc... but then I stopped dugging in the code).

Comment: Yup. +1 for stream_file, for exactly your reasons. If you find that buffer-sequences trigger "partial writing" - which is actually [specified possible behaviour of generalized `asio::async_write` on any `AsyncWriteStream` model](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload5.html#:~:text=This%20operation%20is%20implemented%20in%20terms%20of%20zero%20or%20more%20calls%20to%20the%20stream%27s%20async_write_some%20function%2C%20and%20is%20known%20as%20a%20composed%20operation), you could manually consolidate and use `async_write_some`. .../

Comment: I might do this if only to express the intent. Of course, YMMV and io_uring may already DoTheRightThing under the hood.